# load multiple gojsonschemas for later use

Tags: go, jsonschema

I am trying to manage json validation for my rest API. I have decided to implement using `github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema` package.

```
func (a Auth) Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    src := "file://" + cwd + "/schemas/auth.json"

    schemaLoader := gojsonschema.NewReferenceLoader(src)
    ...
```

Above works fine, but I am not happy, because for every API request, The schema needs to be loaded.

So in my app setup, I want to load ALL schemas into a map of schemas for later use.

```
package schemas

import (
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema"
)

const ext = ".json"

func LoadSchemas() error {
    pathS, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var files = make(map[string]*gojsonschema.jsonReferenceLoader) // This is where I am stuck...
    filepath.Walk(pathS+"/schemas", func(path string, f os.FileInfo, _ error) error {
        if !f.IsDir() {
            if filepath.Ext(path) == ext {
                key := strings.TrimRight(f.Name(), ext)
                files[key] = gojsonschema.NewReferenceLoader("file://" + path)
            }
        }
        return nil
    })

    return nil
}
```

`gojsonschema.NewReferenceLoader("file://" + path)` returns `*jsonReferenceLoader` - jsonReferenceLoader is not exported outside the package.

```
// NewReferenceLoader returns a JSON reference loader using the given source and the local OS file system.
func NewReferenceLoader(source string) *jsonReferenceLoader {
    return &jsonReferenceLoader{
        fs:     osFS,
        source: source,
    }
}
```

Any hints / tips on how to solve the above problem?

Comment: jsonReferenceLoader implements the interface [JSONLoader](https://godoc.org/github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema#JSONLoader), that should be all you need to interact with it.

Comment: @Marc - Could you provide example in an answer and I can accept that as answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @marc's response, you would just use the `JSONLoader` interface instead:

```
var files = make(map[string]gojsonschema.JSONLoader)
```

In Go, any variable/type/function/etc. that starts with a lowercase letter is "private", and therefore not visible outside of that package. Since your code is not part of the `gojsonschema` package, you can't access that type.

Here's an example in the Go Tour:
https://tour.golang.org/basics/3